# How to get some string into single string

Tags: python, string

I would need some help, i write down my code and what i'd like to get, thanks.

```
text = ["Mayhem's neckwear is a STRING OF PEARLS"]
for line in text:
  line = line.split()
  for word in line:
    if word != "Mayhem's" and word.isupper():
      print(word)
```

Output :

```
STRING
OF
PEARLS
```

But i would like to output : STRINGOFPEARLS but not in other list or something like that.
If you need further information let me know.

Comment: `print(word, end='')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without a newline or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `end = ''` this will print it without new line.

```
text = ["Mayhem's neckwear is a STRING OF PEARLS"]
for line in text:
  line = line.split()
  for word in line:
    if word != "Mayhem's" and word.isupper():
      print(word, end = '')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i don't want to print that out, cause i'd need the string to put into a dictionarie.

Comment: @chaft Can you show me the dictionary? By editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you're doing right now (in the last for loop) is iterating through every word.

After that, if it is not `"Mayhem's"` and is uppercase, then you're printing it.
So, you're printing `'STRING'`, and then `'OF'` and then `'PEARLS'`.

Your question is a bit unclear: what do you want to do with the strings you get?

## If you want to add these strings to a list, then you can do this:

```
text = ["Mayhem's neckwear is a STRING OF PEARLS"]
wordList = [] # list to hold words
for line in text:
  line = line.split()
  for word in line:
    if word != "Mayhem's" and word.isupper():
      wordList.append(word)
print(wordList) # prints your final list of words
```

## If you want to combine these strings into a single string, then you can do this:

```
text = ["Mayhem's neckwear is a STRING OF PEARLS"]
wordList = []
for line in text:
  line = line.split()
  for word in line:
    if word != "Mayhem's" and word.isupper():
      wordList.append(word)
finalString = ' '.join(wordList) # this is what you get
print(finalString)
```

I hope this helped! If my answer doesn't do what you wanted it to, you can add a comment, I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! It does want i wanted, i wanted to put the words into a variable and the second option that you write is good for my purpose, thanks !

Comment: Welcome— I'm  happy to help!